# Jboss error Thread trying to unlock when accessing resultSet

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss5.x

Currently I encountered "java.lang.Throwable: Thread trying to unlock" on Jboss EAP 5.2 when try to get data from resultset ResultSet.getDate(). I have no clue why this is happening.
Can anyone provide some possible causes of this?

```
2015-06-01 08:35:18,543 18619353 WARN  [org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8109-7:) Owner is null
2015-06-01 08:35:18,544 18619354 WARN  [org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8109-7:) Thread trying to unlock
java.lang.Throwable: Thread trying to unlock
     at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1568)
     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.unlock(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:318)
     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.broadcastConnectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:455)
     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.connectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:432)
     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkException(WrappedConnection.java:886)
     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedStatement.checkException(WrappedStatement.java:857)
     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.checkException(WrappedResultSet.java:1947)
     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getDate(WrappedResultSet.java:559)
```

Thanks
David

Comment: Which database and jdbc driver are you using? Might be worth posting your code.

Comment: Oracle 11g is the DB we are using and we found something wrong in our query.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue is caused by the query

```
SELECT '07/14/1987' as  birthday FROM person WHERE name = 'david';
```

The birthday is hardcoded as string and at backend, we are try to use

```
Date bDay = rs.getDate('birthday');
```

This caused the issue.

Thanks
David